Generate and Deploy Wheel file to the Databricks Cluster from VS Code
I have a scenario where I need to generate a versioned Wheel file and upload it automatically to a Databricks cluster using VS Code, without creating workflows or jobs like those in Databricks Bundles. My use case is to later use the Wheel file as an importable package in another notebook.
How can I achieve this using the databricks.yml file?
I can use the Databricks bundle, but it requires some tasks to be created in order to generate the wheel file, and I don't need those tasks to be created.

Add more details what you are trying in VS code and expecting results.

You directly install this wheel file using pip install in notebook or in init script providing the path.

@JayashankarGS I am developing a framework that includes several class files containing business logic. I would like to utilize these classes in a Databricks Notebook by packaging them into a Wheel file.

Add you wheel file in cluster libraries or do pip install


Bundles make it possible to describe Databricks resources such as jobs, pipelines, and notebooks as source files. These source files provide an end-to-end definition of a project, including how it should be structured, tested, and deployed, which makes it easier to collaborate on projects during active development.

Assest bundles is not meant for building wheel files, it just uses those resources for different type of task.
In your case you need to build wheel file and import them in cluster or Databricks workspace to use it as packages.
You can use setuptools to build wheel file.
Below is the sample project file structure i am having and contents according to this documentation
├── src
│     └── my_package
│           ├── __init__.py
│           ├── main.py
│           └── my_module.py
└── setup.py

and added below content in setup.py.
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

import src

setup(
  name = "package",
  version = "0.0.1",
  author = "jay",
  packages=find_packages(where='./src'),
  package_dir={'': 'src'},
  entry_points={
    "packages": [
      "main=package.main:main"
    ]
  },
  install_requires=[
    "setuptools"
  ]
)

In main.py i imported  my_module.py and given the packages under src directory to setup.
Similarly, you give details according to your python projects.
Then run below command.
python setup.py bdist_wheel
This will create a wheel file under dist folder.

Import this file in your Databricks workspace

and install it while running the notebook using below command.
pip install <path_to_wheel_file>

or add to clusters library so that every time you no need to do pip install.

or

output:

